# Why is my data disappearing?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC project in which we have a form with multiple fields. These fields can be edited and saved over and there is also a an entry in the SQL database keeps a running history of the edits on that field, appending each new change to the end of it.

For some reason, whenever a "." (period) character is present in a field, it will cause everything before that period to disappear when being rendered - although it is storing in the database correctly. For example for the *Product Description* field:

"New product to sell. Will make us money"

displays as "Will make us money" when I try to render that entry from the database on the view.

If I were to put a period at the end like this "New product to sell. Will make us money." then is would show nothing at all when being rendered on the view.

Here is where I am rendering it on the view:

```
@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FieldHistory.ElementAt(i).PreviousValue)?
                        @Html.Label(Model.FieldHistory.ElementAt(i).PreviousValue):
                        @Html.Label( "Not specified"))
```

**What is it about the use of periods that is causing this text to disappear?**

Comment: Can you put some of your code here?

Comment: Can you add the code that is retrieving the data from the database and populating your model?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is getting confused by '.' as we use it to refer to fields inside an object.

Try using:

```
@Html.Label("", String.Format("{0},Model.FieldHistory.ElementAt(i).PreviousValue))
```

Comment: Try `code`@Html.Display("", String.Format("{0},Model.FieldHistory.ElementAt(i).PreviousValue))`code`